# Displaying entries listed within a category, strange!

Tags: categories, gwcode-categories

I have a strange issue, that I am hoping is something simple, and I'm just missing it.

I have two channels, that have different sets of categories.

In my first channel, I display what child cat it is in via GWcode categories.

```
{exp:gwcode_categories style="linear" last_only="yes" channel="walks" entry_id="{entry_id}"}

<span class="location"><i class="icon-location"></i> <a href="{path='walks/category/{cat_url_title}'}">{cat_name}</a></span>

{/exp:gwcode_categories}
```

This gives me the Url of `domain.com/walks/category/categoryname`

Then I have a template via Switchee, that displays these entries in this category. It uses segment 2 as the case value {category) and then displays the following channel entries tag.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="walks" status="open|new" disable="member_data|category_fields" show_expired="yes" paginate="bottom" limit="10"}

{lv_walkdetails_main}
{lv_pagination}

{if switchee_no_results}

<p>Sorry, no results!</p>

{/if}

{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Now, as I said this displays all the entries that are listed within that category, however when I perform nearly exactly the same thing on another channel, "news", it displays every single entry, regardless as to whats in the URL.

Am I doing something wrong here? Whats the preferred way to showing a list of entries that belong to a certain child category?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, you have no `category` parameter set in the `entries` tag. So right now, the `entries` tag is listing all entries in the channel `walks`.

To make the `entries` tag dynamic based off the current category, I suggest using a addon like [Low Seg2Cat](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-seg2cat) or [URL Helper](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/url-helper) (which I prefer for the extra  helpful variables) to dynamically set the `category` parameter in the `entries` tag.

So, based off your example URL, the category name is in the third segment:

```
{exp:channel:entries 
    category="{segment_3_category_id}"
    channel="walks"
    disable="member_data|category_fields"
    dynamic="no"
    limit="10"
    paginate="bottom"
    show_expired="yes"
    status="open|new"
}
```

Comment: Ahhh! Brilliant! I've just gone in and realised I had Low Seg2Cat, and it was only set to work on the "walks" channel, hence walks was working and news not! Guess its taken a fair bit to familiarise myself with everything, bearing in mind it was built a year ago. Thanks for the help there! :)